# Generate connections table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I looked for this and did not find a solution that would apply to my scenario.

I'm building a database of game devs and I wish to generate a connections table:

I have the following:

```
Employee
(
    name, date of birth, department they work at, task they do
)

Department
(
    department name
)

Task
(
    task name
)
```

and I need to generate a connections table that shows which `department` contributes to which `task`. I would do that by checking for each `employee` their `department` (only one) and `task` (also only one) and upon a match, the `department` contributes to that `task`.

That is the idea but I have to clue how to code it using Oracle

Comment: What do you mean by 'connections table' ? is it a txn table or an output table parking the data from above three tables?

Comment: Uhh sorry to be confusing. I learn this subject in my home language and the teachers' direct translation to English apparently not the best.
When drawing an E/R diagram, that connection would be the diamond shaped stuff. 
So a table that tells what kind of connections are between the two entity tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "department they work at", "task they do"
  FROM Employee;
```

Comment: Yep, that's a clear answer, Thank you for sharing. 
I only would like to know now how to assign the values to a table?

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)
I'm trying it this way but I get errors like `not enough values`

Comment: Another comment, I got it resolved, I just deleted an apparently useless column from my table. No further assistance needed, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should first work out an entity-relationship diagram, that lists the entities you use and with what attributes (and which primary keys), and the relations between those entities. Relationships can be: 1-to-1, 1-to-many and many-to-1, and many-to-many. 
In the last case (M:N relation), the implementation in database tables requires an extra table to record such a  M:N relationship.
The way to implement a 1:N relationship in a table is adding a foreign key in the child table to the primary key of the parent table.

EDIT: I see that you now supplied some details, and it is clear now that EMPLOYEE table is in fact the connection table, so you could simply query that table and show the DEPTID and TASKID (both the primary keys of their respective tables) to have a connection between departments and tasks. See the query in the other answer, and just add an ORDERBY on DEPTID, to show results in the order of DEPTID.